# How to display text based on slider movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with this. 
I am trying to add an if condition to a form having a horizontal slider. I am trying to to display the text based on the way the slider is moved. Can anyone assist me with this please?

html code

```
<form method="get">
Readability: 0.5<input type="range" name="J" min="0.5" max="14" value={{J}} step="0.1" onChange="readabilityVal();">14  
<input type="submit" value="Update!">
</form>
```

javascript

```
<head>   
</script language="Javascript">>

function readabilityVal() 
{ 
  if (read_score >=0.5 and read_score <= 1.5):
                print read_score,"Article for first Grade"
            else if (read_score >1.5 and read_score <=2.5):
                print read_score, "Article suitable for 2nd grade"
            else if (read_score >2.5 and read_score <=3.5):
                print read_score, "Article suitable for 3rd grade"
            else if (read_score >3.5 and read_score <= 4.5):
                print read_score, "Article suitable for 4th grade"
            else if (read_score >4.5 and read_score <= 5.5):
                print read_score, "Article suitable for 5th grade"
            else:
                print "Article suitable for children above 15 years"

  }  
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript Syntax is totally wrong, what you want is written as

```
HTML

    <form method="get" name="myform">Readability: 0.5
    <input type="range" name="J" min="0.5" max="14" value="" step="0.1" onChange="readabilityVal();" />14
    <input type="submit" value="Update!" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
    function readabilityVal() {
    var el = document.forms["myform"]["J"].value;

    if (el >= 0.5 && el <= 1.5) {
        document.write(el + "Article for first Grade");
    } else if (el > 1.5 && el <= 2.5) {
        document.write(el + "Article for first Grade");
    } else if (el > 2.5 && el <= 3.5) {
        document.write(el + "Article for first Grade");
    } else if (el > 3.5 && el <= 4.5) {
        document.write(el + "Article for first Grade")
    } else if (el > 4.5 && el <= 5.5) {
        document.write(el + "Article for first Grade");
    } else {
        document.write("Article for first Grade");
    }

}
```

**[Check the Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chakravarthysm/rbg03h5s/)**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code. Is it what you wanted to achieve?
I used jquery for this example. Have a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/flomath/56yb4gq6/2/.

```
<form method="get">
    Readability: <div id="readabilityValue"></div><input type="range" name="J" min="0.5" max="14" value={{J}} step="0.1" id="readability"> 
<input type="submit" value="Update!">
</form>



$('#readability').on("change mousemove", function() {
    var read_score = $(this).val();
    if (read_score >= 0.5 && read_score <= 1.5) {
        $("#readabilityValue").html("Article for first Grade");
    } else if (read_score >1.5 && read_score <=2.5) {
        $("#readabilityValue").html("Article suitable for 2nd grade");
    } else if (read_score >2.5 && read_score <=3.5) {
        $("#readabilityValue").html("Article suitable for 3rd grade");
    } else if (read_score >3.5 && read_score <= 4.5) {
        $("#readabilityValue").html("Article suitable for 4th grade");
    } else if (read_score >4.5 && read_score <= 5.5) {
        $("#readabilityValue").html("Article suitable for 5th grade");
    }  else {
        $("#readabilityValue").html("Article suitable for children above 15 years");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have a `print` statement, use `console.log` if you need something to be written into the console.